# How to get object for `reject_if`?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Rails documentations mention a `reject_if` here: https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/NestedAttributes/ClassMethods.html

Just wondering if there's a way to get the actual object that is trying to be saved through the `reject_if` method? Something like this:

```
class Person < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :addresses
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :addresses, reject_if: :not_valid?

  def not_valid?(object)
    # The object in this would be the associated address that's trying to save
    object.valid?
  end
end
```

I basically want to ignore the object if the object is not valid instead of running into a `ROLLBACK` when updating the Person with `addresses_attributes`.

Comment: What would be the `object` in this pseudocode? A `Person`? Or attributes for an `Address`?

Comment: And JFYI, you're not using the proc version here.

Comment: I updated my original post. The `object` would be the `Address` that's associated to the `Person`. Also removed references to proc!

Comment: No way to get the object, but you can construct the object yourself. See the linked post.